# How to write a java program that inputs strings to multiple text boxes on a web page and submit its?

Tags: java

my schools class registration system is all about who can type in their CRNs, and hit submit the fastest. I'm looking for some guidance on how to automate the process. I want to be able to input the strings ahead of time, and hit run, and have them be inserted into the text boxes and submitted very quickly. I am currently taking data structures. Only my 2nd cs class, so I only know java. I am not necessarily looking for someone to write my code, just point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't even have to insert things into text boxes

1. Install a proxy server on your computer - one where you can see the requests and responses.
2. Configure your web browser to route requests through the proxy server. (set proxy server setting)
3. Submit your sign on as your normally do, and look at what gets sent in the request. It is likely that the request is sent using POST (google for more info on POST).
4. In any case, once you've got a copy of the REQUEST, you can build an automated process in Java or anything to simply connect to the login URL using a socket / SSH connection and submitting the request again (updated with any time info that needs to be updated)